# Conditional Variance involving i.i.d Normal Variates

Tags: functions, random-variables, normal-distribution, expected-value

$X,Y$ ~ $N(0,1)$ be independent random variables.

Let $Z=X$ signum$(Y)$. and $W=Y$ signum$(X)$

I am supposed to find $E(ZW)$.

My attempt:

$E(ZW)$ =

$E[X*Y, (X>0,Y>0)]$ + $E[X*Y, (X<0,Y<0)]$ + $E[X*-Y, (X<0,Y>0)]$ + $E[-X*Y, (X>0,Y<0)]$ = $4* E[X*Y, (X>0,Y>0)]$ = $2$/$\pi$

Is this right ? If not, then please correct where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$E[ZW]=E\left[X\frac{|Y|}{Y}Y\frac{|X|}{X}\right]=E\left[|X||Y|\right]\underbrace{=}_{\text {indep.}}E[|X|]E[|Y|]\underbrace{=}_{\text{mean of folded normal}}\left(\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^2=\frac{2}{\pi}$$

Comment: Thanks for this answer! This way of solving did not struck me. Is there any problem with my solution?

Comment: Hi Soham, I think you had the right idea but I would probably clean up the presentation a bit and add some details. I think you meant to use iterated expectations? If so, it should look something like $E[ZW]=E[XY|X>0,Y>0]P(X>0,Y>0)+....$ and then probably justify how you get the $2/\pi$ at the end

Comment: yes I wanted to use iterated expectation. But I still had some hesitation using the method I opted. Your method is crystal clear to me. Thanks!